# What happens when a TVS diode "burns"?

Tags: diodes, tvs, diode-clamp

I am trying to use TVS diode to protect Integrated Circuits from surge voltage introduced from exposed connectors.

TVS will be attached in following way.[image]

I wonder what happens if too much of voltage of current is applied to the TVS diode and it "burns".

If it "burns" to open, the circuit will still function normally, only without protection.

However, if it "burns" to short, the circuit will lose it's functionability.

Comment: Normally they fail shorted first.  Then, if there is enough energy in the source they will blow open.

Comment: Me too (what @JohnD said).

Answer (score 6):

1. TVS diodes (Transzorbs) are semiconductors, essentially 2 zener diodes connected back to back. However, a zener diode is designed for continuous current, while Transzorbs are designed for transient surges of high intensity (5kA to 15kA typical) but short duration (<20uS). Typical test current for clamp voltage is 1.00mA constant current, regardless of clamp voltage or body size-at least where I worked at. Pre-fail mode is evident by an increase in clamp voltage. A drift (permanent) more than +5% means it should be replaced to avoid latent failures.
2. The accumulation of heat in the form of ambient plus constant current plus transients combine to melt and/or burn the wafers into one short circuit. *Their fail mode is to short or explode* off the PCB if the follow current is high and is not shut off by fuses or limited by series resistors.
3. Because they have a much lower capacitance than MOV's, and have a much sharper avalanche, they can be and are used to protect digital logic and analog inputs very well, especially if a series resistor with the input of 100 ohms or more is possible.
4. There are some tiny smd versions with a capacitance of only 1.5pF that can be use in RF couplers and surge suppressors to about 2GHZ. They have the same fail mode as their larger cousins, but RF coax is often well grounded and protected.
5. The same cannot be said for test or ATE equipment. TVS devices are crucial to block connection and signal transients to inputs with sensitive semiconductors, and as back-EMF suppression for solenoids, relays and motors.
6. Because they fail so fast, fuses are seldom used to protect Transzorbs. Resistor values offer the best protection, if they are kept below a value that negatively affects signal integrity or needed bandwidth. MOV's are better at absorbing much higher surges for longer durations, and are trusted to protect equipment at the AC mains, even if it is 3-phase 4,160 VAC for well-pump motors. Containing them in fine quartz sand helps dissipate heat and traps debris from exploding devices.

**EDIT:** This answer pertains to TVS devices (Transzorbs) only. Other surge suppression devices such as MOV's, gas discharge tubes and sidacs have different pre-fail modes, though MOV's and sidacs finally fail by shorting. Gas discharge tubes fail by cracking open under constant fault current state, so the final state may be to fail open, or burn and cause arcing from soot.

Comment: They also make single diode TVS parts - like a surge-suppressing zener.

Answer (score 1):

TVS is intended to suppress sudden and very narrow high voltage spikes which may go many folds higher than normal operating voltage and lasts only for a faction of a second at most.

TVS will fail catastrophically if such high voltage stays for even few seconds long. Wattage rating of tvs as high as 600W or 1200W is pretty common. Since power in watts is defined as the rate at which energy change from electrical to heat, one may ask how such small tvs units can operate at such high power level.

The explanation lies on the fact that time involved here is very small.

If in case tvs is shorted permanent, the circuit must fail by blowing a fuse somewhere, or current must be limited by other means, otherwise fire is imminent.

Another point to remember is, tvs seldom fail open.

Comment: They seldom fail open because (I believe) they use unusually robust connections from die to device pin or pad. So the silicon fails and maintains a low-impedance path to ground more or less indefinitely unless there is enough energy to cook off the silicon. I would not say fire is imminent. It depends on how much energy is available. But the TVS will get very hot, and destroy the package (visibly) and probably prevent normal operation of the device.

Comment: If current is not limited fire will definitely occur...

Comment: Well, current is always limited. It just depends on what the limit is. When I was testing this it was a tiny TVS on USB VBUS. There was also a fuse. So I only applied 2x the rated fuse current (after shorting out the fuse). No actual fire occurred on any of the samples I tested. But the OP has not provided any application details so I don't know what will happen to him. He should test if he needs to know.

Comment: Well.... USB is 5volts... Probably you are right. But my experiences with tvs are on mains voltage where they are connected between L and N on 240Vac lines. Having mere single mm lead diameter, tvs will certainly gets very hot blacken even the FR4 type boards.

Comment: The test protocol was supply to 2A/30V. But it never got to 30V because the fuse blew. So I shorted the fuse and ran 2X the fuse rating (don't remember what the fuse was anymore) for 30 minutes or so. These are essentially ESD diodes.